# Writing a .htaccess file for html5mode with a REST api

Tags: angularjs, .htaccess, rest

I am trying to get html5mode to work, and by adding this to my .htaccess file I am able to make it work.

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -f [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteRule ^ - [L]

RewriteRule ^ index.html [L]
```

I have a php file called api.php in the same folder as my index.html file that will handle the backend REST api.

Basicly I want the html5mode to continue working but all requests to for example localhost/api/ ... to be sent to api.php

I tried several lines but it breaks the html5mode.

Would be awesome if I could figure this one out.

Best regards

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This config was suggested on another answer.

```
RewriteEngine on

# if a directory or a file exists, use it directly
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -s [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -l [OR]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} -d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} !/api.php

# otherwise forward it to index.html 
RewriteRule ^.*$ - [NC,L]
RewriteRule ^. /index.html [NC,L]
```